# Ambiguous constraint for UITableView when width >= and <=

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

Trying to set table view width between 290 and 460 points.
It's pretty enough to fir content for the small screens and looks good for the big ones, like iPad Pro.
Also I want to have leading and trailing space >= 20.

Today's the second day I've tried to fix "inequality constraint ambiguity"...
Thanks for the helping!

I'm new in iOS dev so please do not kick me too much :)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: The difference between width for smaller and bigger devices]

Comment: You may not need the leading and trailing constraint

Comment: It's **Ambiguous** because you haven't told auto-layout how wide you want your table view to be. Your constraints say: `minimum width: 290` and `maximum width: 460`. So... how wide should it be? `320`? `371`? `427`? What do you really want to do with your layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, you want your table view to be:

- 20-pts Leading and Trailing
- *unless* that makes the table view wider than 460-pts
- in which case the table view should be centered horizontally

So, to recap my comment... your constraints say to:

- Center the table view horizontally
- make Leading and Trailing `>=` 20-pts
- make Width between `290` and `460`

The problem is that you haven't told auto-layout where between `290` and `460` you want the width to end up.

So, you need a couple more constraints.

Start simple... tableView constrained 20-pts Top / Leading / Trailing and Zero-pts Bottom (all to Safe Area, of course):

[image]

Next, add a ***second set*** of 20-pt Leading and Trailing constraints:

[image]

Now set one pair to `>=`, and give the other pair a Priority less-than required:

[image]

The `Default High 750` priority on the `=` pair of Leading/Trailing constraints tells auto-layout to *"try to pull the sides to 20-pts from the edges, but allow that to break if a conflicting constraint has a higher priority"*, and the `Required 1000` priority on the `>=` pair gives us a **minimum** of 20-pts on each side.

If we switch to Landscape orientation (iPhone 11), everything looks the same... 20-pts Top / Leading / Trailing and Zero-pts Bottom:

[image]

***But...*** your goal is a max-width of `460`, so let's add a Width constraint of `<= 460`:

[image]

We see Red issues with the constraints, because we still haven't given auto-layout quite enough information - so, we'll add a Horizontal Center constraint:

[image]

and here's how it looks on a 9.7" iPad:

[image]

We don't need -- and don't **want** -- the `>= 290` Width constraint. The `= 20` constraints will handle that. And, while unlikely these days, if your app ends up on an iPhone 4s or 1st-gen SE, the view width is only `320`... and `290 + 20 + 20 == 330` and you'd have constraint conflicts.